# Youtube-Search NPM package gives weird results

Tags: javascript, node.js, search, npm, youtube-data-api

I'm using the youtube-serach NPM library with express to find the first youtube video with a song name.

```
app.get("/search", (req, res) => {
  var search = require("youtube-search");

  var SONG = req.query.SONG;

  var opts = {
    maxResults: 10,
    key: "[REDACTED]"
  };

  search(SONG, opts, function(err, results) {
    if (err) return console.log(err);

    res.json(results);
  });
});
```

When I set SONG to "DJ Turn It Up", the first result when you search in the youtube search bar is the youtube video "Yellow Claw - DJ Turn It Up [Official Full Stream]" by Mad Decent.

When I use youtube-search to sear for "DJ Turn It Up" none of the 10 results are the Mad Decent video, and the first result is actually a scene from Riverdale with the song in it, with 1/33 of the views!?!

This happens with other tracks I search too.

I don't get it! I've tried other NPM packages like ytsearch with no luck either!

**Is there anyway to fine tune this or a better alternative?!**

Answer (score 1):

[image]You can use the REST API https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search and pass some parameter to the API call.

The parameters are **q** - that defines the artist name or album name, **key** - a key is generated by making google project use that key and the last parameter is **part** - part parameter in the request specifies which portions of the resource are to be included in the response. For knowing the details like publish date, channel id etc you can pass snippet in your part parameter.

For more details visit - https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/sample_requests

Comment: Using this link "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&q=%22DJ%20TURN%20IT%20UP%22&key=XXXX", my results still didn't show the top result... **How can I just search for the top result, this makes no sense..**

Comment: @TransmissionsDev As you can see above in the image that "DJ Turn It Up" song proivde the first result as "Yellow Claw - DJ Turn It Up [Official Full Stream]" according to your requirement.

Comment: I don't know what to say except that for me the results are simply completely different and do not contain the Offical Stream... https://i.imgur.com/kzh0qZk.png Could it be my API Key?